# Using JMF to get a frame from a video

Tags: java, video, frame, jmf

I have to take in a video file (.mpg or .avi or .mov  ect...) using JMF and where the user stops the video (or pauses) I need to get that frame. If I can get it into a frame buffer then I'm golden (or even save the frame as a image file like jpg). As once I have the frame I just need to get RGB values from the pixels in the frame.(which I already have made a method for)

My issue here is I have not got any experience in JMF, but I have a source file that opens a window and then I can browse for a video file which seems to only work half the time.

I gather this is a bit of a tall order as I am pretty much in the dark on how to do this, and everything I try looking up is not of any real help, if someone knows a link that has some example code that would be wonderful.

Thanks.